# AngularFire: How to update a denormalised array/ object?

Tags: angularfire, denormalized

I am currently using Kato's gist ( https://gist.github.com/katowulf/f78d4a224c06a643ddfa ) to normalize my records with another Firebase path.

The issue I am facing is when I am trying to update my object back to the firebase database: the database does not update (no error message in the console).

My book table looks like this:

```
books:
    -JyDpkQrUozE3L7flpo: {
    title: "title1",
    author: {-JyDpkQrUozE3L7fl1x: true}
    },
    -JyDpkQrUozE3L7flp1: {
    title: "title2",
    author: {-JyDptrrrezE3L7flKx: true}
    },
    -JyDpkQrUozE3L7flp2: {
    title: "title3",
    author: {-JyDpkQrUozE3L7f222: true}
    }
```

My author table looks like this:

```
authors:
    -JyDpkQrUozE3L7flKx: {
        firstname: "jacques",
        lastname: "smith"
    },
    -JyDptrrrezE3L7flKx: {
        firstname: "bill",
        lastname: "halley"
    },
    -JyDpkQrUozE3L7f222: {
        firstname: "john",
        lastname: "ford"
    }
```

My service for normalizedBook looks like this:

```
.factory('NormalizedBook’, ['$firebaseObject', 'firebaseService', function($firebaseObject, firebaseService) {
    var service = $firebaseObject.$extend({
        $$updated: function(snap) {
            var self = this;
            var record = $firebaseObject.prototype.$$updated.call(this, snap);
            firebaseService.$getAuthor( self.authorId ).$loaded().then(function( authorData ) {
                    self.authorFirstName = authorData.authorFirstName;
                    self.authorLastName = authorData.authorLastName;
            });
            return record;
        }
    });
    return service;
}])
```

The firebaseService is just a helper service to retrieve my data:

```
var service = {};
service.refAuthors = new Firebase(FBAuthors);
service.authors = $firebaseArray( refAuthors );
service.$getAuthor = function(id) {
    if( !service.authors.hasOwnProperty(id) ) {
        service.authors[id] = $firebaseObject(service.refAuthors.child(id));
    };
    return service.authors[id];
};
…….
return service;
```

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('booksController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', 'normalizedBook', function($scope, $firebaseArray, normalizedBook) {
    $scope.bookSelected = new normalizedBook(firebaseService.refBooks.child(id);    
    $scope.updateBookSelected = function(item) {
        $scope.bookSelected.$save(item);
    };
});
```

My view renders the expected object (the book and author information within the same object) so everything is working fine. The only issue is really how to update my object back to the firebase database. Any idea on how to do this?